# Angular js Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngroute due to:

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple angularjs app with ngroute. but I am getting the following error. please help me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngroute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "app,html",
        controller: "mycont"
    });
}]);

app.controller('mycont', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "hello";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such module `ngroute`, it's `ngRoute` (and similar `ngResource`). Case matters here. Correct module definition would be:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Also watch, `app,html` in template name.